# Flex includeIn( state of topLevelApplication )

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, state, mxml, flex4.6

In a Flex Mobile App, my Application component handles states like portrait/landscape ios/android and phone/tablet in groups. In my View I want to include a button if the main App has one specific state of these. I don't want any View to check portroit/landscape and stuff again to set as own state. On the other hand the views states are required for other things. So how can I say include the button in my view only if the state of the topLevelApplication is landscape e.g.?

Answer (score 2):

Use the attribute includein="landscape" if it is present in multiple state you can put a comma separated list

Comment: What about FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.state attribute?

Answer (score 0):

First of all add two *states* to your application:

```js
<s:states>
    <s:State name="portrait"/>
    <s:State name="landscape"/>
</s:states>
```

Next, add the following function to your `<fx:Script>` section:

```js
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

        protected function application1_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
        {
            if (width>height)
                this.currentState="landscape";
            else this.currentState="portrait";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Also call the method above on application *resize*:

```js
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160" resize="application1_resizeHandler(event)">
```

Now if you want to include or exclude a component just add *visible* or *includeIn* on the desired component:

```js
visible.landscape="false"
```

or

```js
includeIn="landscape"
```

Full code sample:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       resize="application1_resizeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

            protected function application1_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
            {
                if (width>height)
                    this.currentState="landscape";
                else this.currentState="portrait";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button includeIn="landscape" x="58" y="52" label="Landscape"/>
    <s:Button includeIn="portrait" x="58" y="90" label="Portrait"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Ok that might be the best method to do this. But I would have thought that there could be better solutions since everyone tells you, that for performance reasons includeIn/excludeIn is better than setting visible=false and includeInLayout=false, because objects don't need to be created. And the includeIn/excludeIn are afaik only available with states..

Comment: You are right, but with the above code you do have states and therfor you are able to use `includeIn/excludeIn`. Please see the full code sample above.

Comment: Yeah but I want to access the Applications states in my view component not in my application component. Please see my question.